# Connecting to MS SQL Server through application role in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures, ado

I am rebuilding an VBA application and moving database from Access to SQL Server Management Studio.

I want to add access level for the VBA application rather than add every user to access (Application doing all user validation). Can some one advice what am I doing wrong?
I have created the SQL Application Role to be able to select from certain tables.
I am able to send the username and pw for the application role (which gives read-access to TABLE A), however, I don't know how to make the SQL query afterwards.
Can anyone help me?

I get the following error:

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
> in conflict with one another.

````
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ssql As String

cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Server=*SERVER*;Database=*DATABASE*;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
cmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "sp_setapprole"
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
   cmd(1) = "USERNAME"
   cmd(2) = "PASSWORD"
cmd.Execute

ssql = "SELECT DISTINCT VARIABLE FROM TABLE A  "

Set cmd2 = New ADODB.Command
cmd2.ActiveConnection = cmd.ActiveConnection

Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
RS.Open ssql, cmd2


cmd.ActiveConnection.Close

End sub ```
````

Comment: are `cmd(1)` etc meant to be `cmd.parameters(1)`?

Comment: Side note: You're not moving the application to SQL Server Management Studio. That is just another application to access SQL Server. You're moving the application's database to SQL Server.

Comment: Well yes, `cmd(1)` and `cmd.parameters(1)` works. @Nathan_Sav
I think I explained it wrong @HardCode. I am currently working on a project in which the user fills out a userform in VBA which was previously connected to an Access Database. I am now migrating the back-end part of the userform to an SQL database.